# Problems starting new Kafka Connect SSL-based connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Im trying to setup a new ElasticSearchSink-job on our KafkaConnect cluster. The cluster has been working smoothly for a couple of months with a SASL-SSL secured connection to Kafka and HTTPS to an Elastic-instance on host A. 
The KC-Cluster normally run in Kubernetes but for testing purposes I also run it locally using docker(image based on Confluent's KC-image v6.0.0), the Kafka resides in a test-environment and the job is started using REST-calls.

The docker-composed-file used for running it localy looks like this

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  connect:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.local
      context: ./
    container_name: kafka-connect
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      KAFKA_OPTS: -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/<path-to>/secrets/krb5.conf 
                  -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/<path-to>/rest-basicauth-jaas.conf
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: <KAFKA-INSTANCE-1>:2181,<KAFKA-INSTANCE-2>:2181,<KAFKA-INSTANCE-3>:2181
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka-connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_REST_EXTENSION_CLASSES: org.apache.kafka.connect.rest.basic.auth.extension.BasicAuthSecurityRestExtension
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: <kc-group>
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: service-assurance.test.internal.connect.configs
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: service-assurance.test.internal.connect.offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: service-assurance.test.internal.connect.status
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.IntegerConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: <KAFKA-INSTANCE-1>:2181,<KAFKA-INSTANCE-2>:2181,<KAFKA-INSTANCE-3>:2181
      CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SASL_SSL
      CONNECT_SASL_KERBEROS_SERVICE_NAME: "kafka"
      CONNECT_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required \
                                useKeyTab=true \
                                storeKey=true \
                                keyTab="/<path-to>/kafka-connect.keytab" \
                                principal="<AD-USER>";
      CONNECT_SASL_MECHANISM: GSSAPI
      CONNECT_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION: "/<path-to>/truststore.jks"
      CONNECT_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: <pwd>
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SASL_SSL
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_SASL_KERBEROS_SERVICE_NAME: "kafka"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required \
                                useKeyTab=true \
                                storeKey=true \
                                keyTab="/<path-to>/kafka-connect.keytab" \
                                principal="<AD-USER>";
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_SASL_MECHANISM: GSSAPI
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION: "/<path-to>/truststore.jks"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: <pwd>
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/etc/kafka-connect/jars"
```

With a similar kuberneted-configuration.

The connector is started using something like:

```
curl  -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{
  "name": "connector-name",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": 2,
    "batch.size": 200,
    "max.buffered.records": 1500,
    "flush.timeout.ms": 120000,
    "topics": "topic.connector",
    "auto.create.indices.at.start": false,
    "key.ignore": true,
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": false,
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
    "schema.ignore": true,
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "behavior.on.malformed.documents" : "ignore",
    "behavior.on.null.values": "ignore",
    "connection.url": "https://<elastic-host>",
    "connection.username": "<user>",
    "connection.password": "<pwd>",
    "type.name": "_doc"
  }
}' <host>/connectors/
```

Now, Ive been tasked to setup yet another connector, this time hosted on host B. The problem that I am experiencing is the infamous:

```
    sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I have modified the working truststore to include both the CA-Root-certificate for host B aswell. I belive the truststore is working as I am able to use it from a java code-snippet (actually found on a Atlassian page, SSLPoke.class) to connect to both A and B succesfully.

The connectors connecting to host A still work with the newly updated truststore but not the connector connecting to host B.

I have scanned to internet for clues on how to solve this and come across  suggestions to explicitly add:

```
"elastic.https.ssl.truststore.location": "/<pathto>/truststore.jks",
"elastic.https.ssl.truststore.password": "<pwd>",
```

To the connector-configuration. Some other page suggested adding the truststore to the KC-configuration KAFKA_OPTS as such:

```
  KAFKA_OPTS: -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/<path-to>/secrets/krb5.conf 
              -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/<path-to>/rest-basicauth-jaas.conf
              -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/<path-to>/truststore.jks
```

Following these suggestions I can actually get the connector connecting to host B to start succefully. But now comes the anoying part. With adding the extra param to KAFKA_OPTS my old connectors connecting to A stops working!! - with the exact same error! So now I have a case of either having connectors connecting to A OR connectors connecting to B working, but not at the same time.

Please, If anyone could give me some pointers or ideas on how to fix this it would be much appreciated, cause this is driving me nuts.